# SQL CHECK constraint confusion

Tags: sql, mysql

Hello guys I had this question on my SQL exam and I do not know what the answer should be. Can you help me?

The table Employees, among others, contains a column called "Country" with a length of 3 characters and a column called "State" with a maximum length of 30 characters. If the value 'USA' is present in the "Country" column, then the "State" column should only contain two characters. For other values in the "Country" column, the "State" column can contain 0, 1, 2, or a maximum of 30 characters. Which of the following check constraints will ensure that the entered or modified data comply with the given requirements?

A)
Country = 'USA' AND LEN(State) =2

B)
Country = 'USA' OR LEN(State) =2

C)
Country <> 'USA' AND LEN(State) = 2

D)
Country <> 'USA' OR LEN(State) = 2

My teacher is saying that the right answer is D), but I just can't wrap my head around that answer and How it would make sense. I thought that A) is the answer since both 'USA' and length should return true in order to be inserted. I think that D) answer would allow inserting values like 'USA' and 'FILA' since or will return true if one of ether is true.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"I think that D) answer would allow inserting values like 'USA' and 'FILA' since or will return true if one of ether is true."_ - right, but consider "both" instead of "either" - then you'll see why it works.

Comment: Well it would allow inserting values that I want and those that I don't want? Right? But A) would ensure that if it's USA it must have 2 characters? If it isn't USA it will enter what ever?

Comment: I think you're getting thrown-off by how `OR` and `AND` in SQL are Disjunctive and Conjunctive respectively, whereas in verbal/spoken English-language "or" is generally Conjunctive and not Disjunctive. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_(logical_connective) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction

Comment: It's D but it should also ensure country is not null and state is not null. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @TheImpaler I thought `CHECK` constraints are evaluated even if the column is `NULL` - but because `NULL` comparisons fail _virally_ (like `NaN` in IEEE-754) it still works-out in the end?

Comment: Yeah, I got it.. If USA or len 2 => true, USA or len 1 => false, !USA will return true always...

Comment: @Dai Unlike selection with WHERE or HAVING, constraints fail only when evaluate to **false**. They succeed when they evaluate to **true** or to **unknown**.

Comment: @TheImpaler Right, I meant to say `unknown`.

Comment: Just to be clear, answer A) would only allow insertions of USA and len 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a preface, in SQL, and in computer-programming in general, `OR` is a *logical disjunction* - whereas in spoken English language "or" is generally used [as a *logical conjunction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) (i.e. "and" or "both").

When looking at an expression involving `AND` or `OR`, remember that it means you need to evaluate each operand (left-side and right-side) of the `OR` expression *independently*, and the entire expression is either `TRUE` or `FALSE` (or `UNKNOWN` if you have SQL `NULL`s) [according to this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) (`NULL`/`UNKNOWN` omitted for brevity):

| Combinator | Left-hand-side | Right-hand-side | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [`OR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_(logical_connective)) | `TRUE` | `TRUE` | `TRUE` |
| `OR` | `TRUE` | `FALSE` | `TRUE` |
| `OR` | `FALSE` | `TRUE` | `TRUE` |
| `OR` | `FALSE` | `FALSE` | `FALSE` |
|  |  |  |  |
| [`AND`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) | `TRUE` | `TRUE` | `TRUE` |
| `AND` | `TRUE` | `FALSE` | `FALSE` |
| `AND` | `FALSE` | `TRUE` | `FALSE` |
| `AND` | `FALSE` | `FALSE` | `FALSE` |

To save time, I'll just post some example data for each possible interpretation:

---

> A: `Country = 'USA' AND LEN(State) = 2`

| `Country` | `State` | Expected Result | Actual Result | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'USA' | 'WA' | OK | OK | `'USA' = 'USA'` - and also `LEN('WA') = 2` |
| 'USA' | 'Foobar' | Fail | Fail | `LEN('Foobar') = 6` not `2` |
| 'Canada' | 'NB' | OK | Fail | `'Canada' <> 'USA'` |
| 'Canada' | 'Foobar' | OK | Fail | `'Canada' <> 'USA'` - and also: `LEN('Foobar') = 6` not `2` |

---

> B: `Country = 'USA' OR LEN(State) = 2`

| `Country` | `State` | Expected Result | Actual Result | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'USA' | 'WA' | OK | OK | `'USA' = 'USA'` - and also `LEN('WA') = 2` |
| 'USA' | 'Foobar' | Fail | OK | `'USA' = 'USA'` - the `LEN` term is ignored |
| 'Canada' | 'NB' | OK | OK | `LEN('NB') = 2` - the `'Canada' <> 'USA'` term is ignored) |
| 'Canada' | 'Foobar' | OK | Fail | `'Canada' <> 'USA'` - and also `LEN('Foobar') = 6` not `2` |

---

> C: `Country <> 'USA' AND LEN(State) = 2`

| `Country` | `State` | Expected Result | Actual Result | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'USA' | 'WA' | OK | Fail | `'USA' <> 'USA'` is false - even though the `LEN(State)` part of the check passes using `AND` means *both sides* of the `AND` must succeed for a pass. |
| 'USA' | 'Foobar' | Fail | Fail | `'USA' <> 'USA'` is false - and `LEN('Foobar') = 6` not `2` - so both sides of the `AND` fail. |
| 'Canada' | 'NB' | OK | OK | `'Canada' <> 'USA'` and also `LEN('NB') = 2` |
| 'Canada' | 'Foobar' | OK | Fail | `'Canada' <> 'USA'`, but `LEN('NB') = 6` |

---

> D: `Country <> 'USA' OR LEN(State) = 2`

| `Country` | `State` | Expected Result | Actual Result | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'USA' | 'WA' | OK | OK | `'USA' <> 'USA'` is false, but as this is an `OR` condition, the `LEN('WA') = 2` part passes. |
| 'USA' | 'Foobar' | Fail | Fail | `'USA' <> 'USA'` is false, so this can still pass *if* `LEN(State) = 2`, but in this case it's `LEN('Foobar') = 6` so it fails |
| 'Canada' | 'NB' | OK | OK | `'Canada' <> 'USA'` is true, we can ignore the `LEN(State)` clause, but *even if* we did, that would also pass as `LEN('NB') = 2`. |
| 'Canada' | 'Foobar' | OK | OK | `'Canada' <> 'USA'` is true, we can ignore the `LEN(State)` clause |

Answer (score 2):

D would be the right answer, if a country is not equal to USA, the check constraint will not block, if USA is the country will not block only when the the state has only 2 letters, else it reports an error see sample

```
CREATE TABLE employee (State varchar(3), Country Varchar(30)
  ,CONSTRAINT `state_county_chk` CHECK (Country <> 'USA' OR CHAR_LENGTH(State) = 2))
```

```
INSERT into employee VALUES ('mic','USA')
```

> ```
> Check constraint 'state_county_chk' is violated.
> ```

```
INSERT into employee VALUES ('mic','GERMANY')
```

```
INSERT into employee VALUES ('MI','USA')
```

```
SELECT * FROM employee
```

| State | Country |
| --- | --- |
| mic | GERMANY |
| MI | USA |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yBxewVmK)